# Should I finish How to Prove it by Velleman or any other proof technique book before starting Stephen Abbott's Understanding Analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, soft-question, proof-explanation

I've heard Stephen Abbott's Analysis is a pretty good book for introduction to Analysis. So I checked the book, proofs and examples are explained in great detail, but exercises seemed hard to me.
Should I finish How to Prove it by Velleman or any other proof technique before starting Stephen Abbott's? I've already read first two chapters of Velleman's book : Logic and Quantifiers.

Comment: Honestly, I jumped into Abbott without any background in proofs just some calculus and found it readable. I'd say go for it

Comment: Abbott's book is pretty approachable.  You should be fine.